# add column based on values in other columns data frame r

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm curious about how to solve this problem. I have data frame like this:

```
a    b    
1    0    
1    0
0    1
1    1
0    0
1    0
```

Then the output has an extra column based on values of "a" and "b":

if(a==1&b==1) c=1, if(a==1&b==0) c=2, if(a==0&b==1) c=3, else c=4.

```
a    b    c
1    0    2
1    0    2
0    1    3
1    1    1
0    0    4
1    0    2
```

Any thoughts? I don't to write a for loop with nested if-else, how could we go vectorize? Thanks!

Comment: df$c=ifelse( df$a==1 &df$b==1, 1, ifelse( df$a==1 & df$b==0, 2, ifelse(df$a==0 & df$b==1, 3, 4)))

Comment: Good point! I totally forget this... thanks

Comment: Check out `switch()` too

Comment: Base R or from a package?

Comment: For switch()? It's a base R function.

Comment: `df$c <- 4 - 2 * df$a - df$b`

Comment: I see, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @alistaire that was a great one, thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think switch() will work for this.

Comment: @CephBirk You could use `dplyr::case_when`, which is an extended version of `switch`: `df %>% mutate(c = case_when(.$a == 1 & .$b == 1 ~ 1, .$a == 1 & .$b == 0 ~ 2, .$a == 0 & .$b == 1 ~ 3, TRUE ~ 4))` though it annoyingly messes up dplyr's NSE.

Comment: @alistaire exactly, dplyr is assumed to be neat and clean, anyway know different thoughts from u guys really help a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`interaction` is made for this:

```
c(4,2,3,1)[interaction(df)]
#[1] 2 2 3 1 4 2
```

Comment: This is crazily simple. Nice find!

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join (df, cbind(expand.grid(0:1, 0:1), c=c(4, 2, 3, 1)), 
                by=c('a'='Var1', 'b'='Var2'))

  a b c
1 1 0 2
2 1 0 2
3 0 1 3
4 1 1 1
5 0 0 4
6 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of linear algebra:

we need to solve for x,y from the equation c = 4 - x*a - y*b
we can see x = 2, y = 1 is the solution given the set of variable values

```
 a  b c
 0  0 4
 1  0 2
 0  1 3
 1  1 1
```

or we can use the limSolve to solve this over-determined set of equations:

```
library(limSolve)
res <- Solve(as.matrix(expand.grid(0:1, 0:1)), 4-c(4, 2, 3, 1))
res
Var1 Var2  # a = Var1, b = Var2
   2    1
```

Hence, we have:

```
df$c <- 4 - res[1]*df$a - res[2]*df$b
df
a b c
1 1 0 2
2 1 0 2
3 0 1 3
4 1 1 1
5 0 0 4
6 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Map your desired c-values to a vector and use a and b values as indices (increment by 1 for 1-based indexing).

```
foo <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,0,1,0,1), b=c(0,0,1,1,0,0))

data.frame(foo, c=c(4:1)[foo$a*2 + foo$b + 1])

#   a b c
# 1 1 0 2
# 2 1 0 2
# 3 0 1 3
# 4 1 1 1
# 5 0 0 4
# 6 1 0 2
```